# Why Hbase doesn't use all nodes in the cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm setting up a Hbase cluster and I ran into a problem. When I'm writing my data to the cluster some nodes remain empty.

Hbase Status Screen :

[image]
Dfshealth screen :
[image]

> Hbase 1.4.10, Hadoop 3.1.2

node-master hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
      <value>hdfs://node-master:9000/hbase</value>

   </property>

   <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
      <value>hdfs://node-master:9000/zookeeper</value>
   </property>

   <property>
     <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
     <value>true</value>
   </property>


   <property>
           <name>hbase.zookeper.quorum</name>
           <value>node-master</value>
   </property>

   <property>
           <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
           <value>2181</value>
   </property>
   <property>
           <name>hbase.client.write.buffer</name>
           <value>8388608</value>
   </property>
   <property>
           <name>hbase.client.scanner.caching</name>
           <value>10000</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

node-master regionservers (hadoop workers same)

```
node1
node2
node3
node4
node5
node6
```

Answer (score 0):

Hbase writes data in regions where each region is a collection of rows based on sorted keys. When you reach a region limit HBase split the region into 2 regions and same when 2nd region reach limit it again split. each region is assigned to a region server(Datanode).

So your table does not have as many regions that it will utilize all the nodes. so to balance the data across nodes you can either pre-split the table while creating it.
[Hbase Table Pre-split](https://hortonworks.com/blog/apache-hbase-region-splitting-and-merging/)

Please also read about HBase hotspot problem then you get more understanding.